# MYSQL check input values or pass in null. In a PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a stored procedure to add a new customer to a table named customers. I want to define the values but even if I choose to leave a field out that those field will be set to NULL and not to a blank string as it is now in the code. I have been thinking about how I can possibly write an if statement or a loop to check the input values.

I work in MySQL Workbench 8.0 if its to any help.
I did add a screenshot of the staff table under the code.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_customer;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_customer

(
in First_name TEXT, 
in Last_name TEXT, 
in Email VARCHAR(255), 
in Adress TEXT, 
in Postcode TEXT, 
in Country TEXT, 
in City TEXT, 
in Phone TEXT,
-- in Points DECIMAL(9,2), 
in Social_security_no TEXT,
in org_no TEXT,
in memberNO TEXT
)

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO customers (id_customer, first_name, last_name, email, adress, postcode, country, city, phone, social_security_no, org_no, memberNO)

VALUES (DEFAULT , first_name, last_name, email, adress, postcode, country, city, phone,  social_security_no, org_no, memberNO );

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[Screenshoot of the customers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2PIg.png)

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure to run an extremely simple query?

Comment: Tip: Skip `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns in inserts like this, just omit the column and the extraneous `DEFAULT` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nullif(varName,''). This will return null whn varName field is empty string. Use this on fields you want to:

```
INSERT INTO customers (id_customer, first_name, last_name, email, adress, postcode, country, city, phone, social_security_no, org_no, memberNO)

VALUES (DEFAULT , nullif(first_name,''), nullif(last_name,''), nullif(email,''), nullif(adress,''), nullif(postcode,''), nullif(country,''), nullif(city,''), nullif(phone,''),  nullif(social_security_no,''), nullif(org_no,''), nullif(memberNO ,''));
```